# QGIS Scale print of ground surface profile

Tags: qgis, scale, profile

I am trying to print a scale version of a ground profile generated using either Profile or QProf.

Neither of these tools seems to allow me to print to scale so that I can measure with a ruler both distance and height on the printed version.

Can anyone make any suggestions for how I can achieve this?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you achieved until now ? Do you expect the profile to be rendered in QGIS, or export data for rendering elsewhere ?

Comment: Hi Kasper - I have successfully generated the ground profile using Profile.  I would like to print a version of the profile for inclusion in a report.  Ideally, this would be achieved within QGIS, but if not then via another software product.  I have tried export to excel but it seems very difficult to control the scale of the printed version in excel.  Just to clarify, I want the printed version to be rendered to scale (say 1:200) so that a scale rule can be use to measure from it.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Then you might want to use your profile importing it as a delimted text layer (see full suggestion in the Answer section)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do with QGIS, assuming your profile has the longitudinal distance along the profile (X) and the profile height (Y) in meters, is to open the profil as a `Delimited Text Layer` , in a meter based CRS like WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator.

Your geometry will show up near the 0,0 coordinates (Gulf of Guinea), with the scale being respected as long as the geometry is limited to a few km in extent.

Example below uses a profile generated by the qProf plugin: `cds2d` is the desired longitudinal unit, `z` is the profile height

Open it as a Delimited text layer and "zoom to layer" to see it:
[image]

If needed create a path (points to path) layer to get a line. You might want to add other geometries to represent the sea level (black line with a marker every 500m in the screenshot below)/ vertical frames.

Then in the Layout manager, set whatever you need in terms of rendering and scale (1:30000 here):

[image]

With that, you have both the relative x/y scale and absolute scale handled. And playing with the Geometry generator, you can probably do some really nice things with the profile